# Замена символа в массиве

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, как заменить один знак другим в массиве. Для примера: имеем объект, который путем перебора выводится как массив, например:

```
var obj = {Alphabet : [Aa], [Bb], [Cc]}
var res = [];
for (var key in obj) {
        res.push(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
    }
console.log(res) // ["Alphabet: Aa,Bb,Cc"]
```

Применить метод `replace` я не могу (это метод строки, а не массива). Необходимо получить:

```
["Alphabet: Aa, Bb, Cc"]
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Нужно чтобы были пробелы ?

Comment: @Netahaki угу, чтобы пробелы появились

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  Alphabet: ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc']
};

var objLength = obj.Alphabet.length;

for (var i = 1; i < objLength; i++) {
  obj.Alphabet[i] = (' ' + obj.Alphabet[i]);
}

var res = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  res.push(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
}
console.log(res);
```